# Open SMS Inbox in iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to open the SMS inbox when I touched a button in my app. I can write message using `MFMessageComposeViewController`, is there a counterpart for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sms URL scheme on the iPhone for this. Use the following code to open the Messages app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms://"]];
```

Apple documents the sms: URL scheme in some detail [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html)

As has already been pointed out, if you wish to do this entirely in-app, you will have to jailbreak your device. The messages database is not accessible through the app sandbox, as it used to be in earlier (pre-4.0) versions of iOS.

Comment: what if i want to show sms inbox? is it possible?                    this - [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms://"]]; creates a new SMS.